# Set active element to menu if url have custom character

Tags: javascript, php, html-lists

I have URL on string like `Cat-115/ID-12/Ads-748-49` and I want to be set `active` to my `a`

I want, if in my URL the number after /ID-`12` same with A id Set Active element to a Class

HTML :

```
<div class="primary-nav">
    <a id="ID-1" class="list-group-item " href="/Cat-118/ID-1">number 1</a>
    <a id="ID-4" class="list-group-item " href="/Cat-118/ID-4">number 4</a>
    <a id="ID-3" class="list-group-item Active" href="/Cat-118/ID-3">number 3</a>  // Like this
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
    <script>

    $(function () {
        var url = window.location.pathname; 
        var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            $('.primary-nav a').each(function () { 
                var linkPage = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('ID-') + 1); 
                if (activePage == linkPage) { 
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }
            });
    })
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help my friends!

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: i think you need `this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('ID-') + '1');`

Comment: Not work.........!

Comment: add `console.log(activePage, linkPage);` before if to see what values are comparing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname; 
    var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/ID-') + 1);
    var activeID = activePage.substring(0, activePage.indexOf("/"))
    if($('a#'+activeID)) 
      $('a#'+activeID).addClass("active")
})
```

Comment: can you check this, https://jsfiddle.net/wL93kew7/ , it will work if you are getting `url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);` correctly

Comment: with your jsfiddle, active added but my problem is my current URL is `/Cat-118/ID-1/Ads-567-41`

Comment: @Zandb try it now

Comment: Thank you very much mr  Aswin Ramesh it WORK

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        var url = window.location.pathname; 
        var activePage = url.substring(url.indexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
            $('.primary-nav a').each(function () { 
                var linkPage = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('ID-') ); 
                if (activePage == linkPage) { 
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }
            });
    })
```